# C# SQL DataTable: adding a column of custom type

Tags: c#, sql, types, datatable, ado

I want to call a stored procedure on my SQL database (MSSQL 2008 R2) using a table-valued parameter.  I can do that fine with something like

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(int)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));

table.Rows.Add(55, "hello");
table.Rows.Add(66, "goodbye");
```

Then later on I construct an `SqlParameter` object whose type is `SqlDbType.Structured` and whose value is `table`.  That all works.

The set of column types supported by `DataTable` appears to be fixed.  Most SQL primitive types have their C# equivalent, but there is nothing directly corresponding to the `date` type supported by MSSQL.  We have `DateTime` in C#, of course, but that is more general.  As it happens I have my own simple class `MyDate` to represent dates.  It supports a conversion method `ToDateTime()`.

I would like to teach `DataTable` about this new type so that I'll be able to do

```
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DateColumn", typeof(MyDate)));
table.Rows.Add(new MyDate(2018, 10, 11));
```

Currently, if I try this I get

```
System.ArgumentException:
The type of column 'DateColumn' is not supported.
The type is 'MyDate'
```

Is there some interface that `MyDate` should implement so that `DataTable` will support it?  Ideally, I would like to specify a conversion to `DateTime`, which obviously is already handled by `DataTable`.  I don't really want to add support for the custom type all the way through the SQL stack down to encoding it on the wire (which is what `SqlUserDefinedAggregate` seems to be about).

I have tried implementing `IConvertible` and `ISerializable`; it's not that.  I hoped that the `System.Data.SqlTypes` namespace would contain an `SqlDate` type I could use instead of my custom type, but it doesn't.

Obviously I can just use `DateTime` and convert when adding the values.  That is what I have done so far.  But the `MyDate` type is used in a lot of my code base (the convention is to use it for dates, while `DateTime` is used when we need both date and time), the SQL `date` type is used in the database, and I'd like to make the code cleaner if I can.  Hence I ask, how can I make `DataTable` support this custom type, or custom types in general?

Comment: Did you try making your MyDate class Serializable?

Comment: @dcp I just tried that -- with a dummy implementation that throws if it is ever called.  The result is the same: "not supported".  I don't believe that DataTable is checking for ISerializable, or calling the method if it exists.

Comment: Another option would be to make the DataColumn of type "Object", then you can cast it to MyDate when you need to use it.  That's not very elegant, but it may be a good workaround for your scenario.

Comment: What is wrong with DateTime type? That is what MS SQL Date implicitly casts to and from seamlessly. Even a DateTime value with some time portion can implicitly be casted to a Date. Its display format is also "Date" style in a DataGridView if you are using default controls. There is no conversion needed. And in cased you need an explicit conversion there is Date property of DateTime structure.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with DateTime.  Similarly, there's nothing wrong with float.  But where a value is a whole integer and there will never be any fractional part, we prefer to use int instead.

Comment: @dcp I am creating a DataTable solely to pass as a table-valued parameter to a stored proc.  The DataTable isn't used for any other purpose.